# Converting Names into Identification Codes in different columns in R

Tags: r

I am new with R and I am struggling with the following issue:

I have a dataset more or less like this:

```
NAME                     Collegue1                  Collegue 2
John Smith               Bill Gates                 Brad Pitt
Adam Sandler             Bill Gates                 John Smith
Bill Gates               Brad Pitt                  Adam Sandler
Brad Pitt                John Smith                 Bill Gates
```

I need to create an ID code and substitute names with the corresponding ID in the three columns, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try the code like below

```
df[]<-as.integer(factor(unlist(df),levels = df$NAME))
```

such that

```
> df
  NAME Collegue1 Collegue2
1    1         3         4
2    2         3         1
3    3         4         2
4    4         1         3
```

---

Or

```
df[-1] <- as.integer(factor(unlist(df[-1]),levels = df$NAME))
```

such that

```
> df
          NAME Collegue1 Collegue2
1   John Smith         3         4
2 Adam Sandler         3         1
3   Bill Gates         4         2
4    Brad Pitt         1         3
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(NAME = c("John Smith", "Adam Sandler", "Bill Gates", 
"Brad Pitt"), Collegue1 = c("Bill Gates", "Bill Gates", "Brad Pitt", 
"John Smith"), Collegue2 = c("Brad Pitt", "John Smith", "Adam Sandler", 
"Bill Gates")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: This seems fine. Only, my dataset has 230 row and some of the names in Collegue1 and Collegue2 are not present in NAME. I would like to convert all names in the dataset into ID Codes, with ID Codes corresponding when names appear more than once, in different columns. Also, I would like missing values to appear as missing values, and not be susbstitute by ID Codes. Does that seem possible?

Comment: @AldoP Could you show an example for that in your post?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the names to a `factor` and use `unclass` to get the ID codes.

```
x[-1] <- unclass(factor(unlist(x[-1]), x$NAME))
cbind(x["NAME"], ID=seq_along(x$NAME), x[-1])
#          NAME ID Collegue1 Collegue.2
#1   John Smith  1         3          4
#2 Adam Sandler  2         3          1
#3   Bill Gates  3         4          2
#4    Brad Pitt  4         1          3
```

In case you are just interested in ID's:

```
levels(factor(unlist(x))) #Only in case you are interested in the codes of the table
#[1] "Adam Sandler" "Bill Gates"   "Brad Pitt"    "John Smith"
x[] <- unclass(factor(unlist(x)))
x
#  NAME Collegue1 Collegue.2
#1    4         2          3
#2    1         2          4
#3    2         3          1
#4    3         4          2
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(NAME = c("John Smith", "Adam Sandler", "Bill Gates", 
"Brad Pitt"), Collegue1 = c("Bill Gates", "Bill Gates", "Brad Pitt", 
"John Smith"), Collegue.2 = c("Brad Pitt", "John Smith", "Adam Sandler", 
"Bill Gates")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first example is exactly what I need. Only, whan I try to implement it, I get the following Error:Errore: Assigned data `unclass(factor(unlist(Survey_Data[, c("name", "Collegue1")]), Survey_Data$name))` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 230 rows.
x Assigned data has 460 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.      Any idea?

Comment: Try: `Survey_Data[, c("name", "Collegue1")] <- unclass(factor(Survey_Data[, c("name", "Collegue1")]))`

Comment: It gives me: Errore: Assigned data `unclass(factor(Survey_Data[, c("name", "Collegue1")]))` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 230 rows.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled. What do you think?

Comment: Try: `le <- levels(factor(unlist(Survey_Data[, c("name", "Collegue1")])))` `Survey_Data$name <- unclass(factor(Survey_Data$name, le))` `Survey_Data$Collegue1 <- unclass(factor(Survey_Data$Collegue1, le))`

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried Survey_Data[,c("name","Collegue1")][-1] <- unclass(factor(unlist(Survey_Data[,c("name","Collegue1")][-1]), Survey_Data[,c("name","Collegue1")]$name))
cbind(Survey_Data[,c("name","Collegue1")]["name"], ID=seq_along(Survey_Data[,c("name","Collegue1")]$name), Survey_Data[,c("name","Collegue1")][-1]).  The output is perfect, but the variable ID does not appear in my dataset Survey_Data as a new variable. Any idea how to do that?